# How to don't use pipe if value is empty

Tags: angular

I got simple table where I using Pipe - split which looks like:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({ name: 'split' })

export class SplitRecipientsPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(rec: any) {
    return rec
      .split(',')
      .filter(Boolean)
      .map(r => r.trim());
  }
}
```

And my table looks like

```
<tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let r of recipients.recipients | split; let i = index">
            <td>{{r}}</td>
                <td style="width: 60px"><button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger"
                  (click)="_delete(r, recipients, aliases)">Delete</button></td>
        </tr>
</tbody>
```

it works fine when `r` is not empty but when `r` is empty - split Pipe still works and makes problems.

How can I only call this pipe when `r` is not empty?

Comment: "makes problems". What problems exactly?

Answer (score 1):

return like this

```
return rec ? rec.split(',').filter(Boolean).map(r => r.trim()) : [];
```

Also your *ngFor will give error if the iterations is not array

Answer (score 0):

I did it like this:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({ name: 'split' })

export class SplitRecipientsPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(rec: any) {
    if(rec === null || rec === 0 || rec === undefined){
      console.log('empty');
    } else {
      return rec
      .split(',')
      .filter(Boolean)
      .map(r => r.trim());
    }
  }
}
```